# Importing a method faills with Mono.Cecil

Tags: mono.cecil

I have a source code of class TestClass stored as string and I need to create a dll with another class, containing the code from the single method of the TestClass. Here is the TestClass, stored as string:

```
namespace Test
{
    public static class TestClass
    {
        public static void TestMethod()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("something");
        }
    }
}
```

I compile this code, using CSharpCodeProvider, then using Mono.Cecil create new assembly, create new type, new method and copy (actually clone) to it instructions of the compiled method. What doesn't work is at the stage of writing the assembly to disk, an exception is thrown:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occured in Mono.Cecil.dll
Additional information: Member 'System.Void System.Console::WriteLine(System.String)' is declared in another module and needs to be imported.

The Console.WriteLine method is imported as stated [here in docs](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/Importing)

Here is the full code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.CreateAssembly(
            new AssemblyNameDefinition("Test", new Version(1, 0)), "module", ModuleKind.Console);
        var type = new TypeDefinition("Test", "TestClass", TypeAttributes.Public);
        var methodDefinition = new MethodDefinition(
            "TestMethod",
            MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public,
            assemblyDefinition.MainModule.Import(typeof(void)));
        type.Methods.Add(methodDefinition);
        assemblyDefinition.MainModule.Types.Add(typeDefinition);
        AddMethodBody(methodDefinition);
        assemblyDefinition.Write("generated.dll");
    }

    private static void AddMethodBody(MethodDefinition methodDefinition)
    {
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(x => x.Location).ToArray());
        var result = _compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, TestClassSource);

        var compiledAssembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssemblly(result.CompiledAssembly.Location);
        var type = compiledAssembly.MainModule.Types.First(x => x.FullName == "Test.TestClass");
        var method = type.Methods.First(x => x.Name == "TestMethod");

        var instructions = method.Body.Instructions;

        var ctorInfo = typeof(Instruction).GetConstructor(
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null,
            new[] { typeof(OpCode, typeof(object) }, null);

        foreach(var inst in instructions)
        {
            var newInstruction = (Instruction)ctorInfo.Invoke(new[] {inst.OpCode, inst.Operand});
            methodDefinition.Body.Instructions.Add(newInstruction);
        }

        var il = methodDefinition.Body.GetILProcessor();
        var ldstr = il.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, methodDefinition.Name);
        var class = il.Create(OpCodes.Call,
            methodDefinition.Module.Import(typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { typeof(string) })));

        il.InsertBefore(methodDefinition.Body.Instructions[0], ldstr);
        il.InsertAfter(methodDefinition.Body.Instructions[0], call);
    }

    private static string TestClassSource = 
@"
namespace Test
{
    public static class TestClass
    {
        public static void TestMethod()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(""abc"");
        }
    }
}"

}
```

Any help would be appreaciated